# Check for word in string with unpredictable delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuzzy-search

I am looking for something slightly more reliable for unpredictable strings than just checking `if "word" in "check for word"`.

To paint an example, lets say I have the following sentence:

```
"Learning Python!"
```

If the sentence contains "Python", I'd want to evaluate to true, but what if it were:

```
"Learning #python!"
```

Doing a split with a space as a delimiter would give me `["learning", "#python"]` which does not match `python`.

(Note: While I do understand that I could remove the `#` for this particular case, the problem with this is that 1. I am tagging programming languages and don't want to strip out the `#` in `C#`, and 2. This is just an example case, there's a lot of different ways I could see human typed titles including these hints that I'd still like to catch.)

I'd basically like to inspect if beyond reasonable doubt, the sequence of characters I'm looking for is there, despite any weird ways they might mention it. What are some ways to do this? I have looked at fuzzy search a bit, but I haven't seen any use-cases of looking for single words.

The end goal here is that I have tags of programming languages, and I'd like to take in the titles of people's stream titles and tag the language if its mentioned in the title.

Comment: Isn't it just a simple regex question? I mean, doesn't regex fit your demand?

Comment: @Sraw yes it appears so, but regex is a huge weakness I need to learn more about for sure, as I've only really used it for validation, not string matching, so I forget the capabilities.

Comment: Just pointing out, extracting the meaning of a particular word usage is a super hard unsolved problem in general, especially in the presence of colloquialisms or typos. I'm reminded of my speech-impaired friend telling me through a strong _lisp_ while cooking up another _batch_ of _java_ about the time he went to _bash_ in a _python_ as it tried to _curl_ around his dear wife _julia_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code prints `True` if the word contains ‘python’, ignoring case.

```py
import re

input = "Learning Python!"
print(re.search("python", input, re.IGNORECASE) is not None)
```

Comment: `re.search()` looks like a great option, thank you! Made a repl for testing, and it seems to match all the cases I can think of. 

https://repl.it/repls/AnnualAnxiousMatch#main.py

Comment: Just thought I should mention. The string passed as the first argument in `re.search()` is regex, so certain characters you will have to escape with a \. For example, `+` would need to be escaped with `\+`

Comment: I did run into that issue and was able to rectify with `re.escape("c+")` for any future readers that may get a multiple repeat error. Thanks for your help, Robert, was able to get this implementation in a good spot with this answer.